# Can a sequence of von Neumann algebras determine a maximal directed set of subalgebras?

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Can a von Neumann algebra $A$ have an infinite sequence $A_0 \subset A_1 \subset A_2 \subset ...$ of sub-vN-algebras such that every other sub-vN-algebra $B \subseteq A$ satisfies, for some $n \geq 0$ and finite $F \subseteq A$, either (1) $B \subseteq (A_n \cup F)''$, or (2) $(A_n \cup B \cup F)'' = A$?

Since the double-commutant $X''$ is the smallest vN algebra that includes $X$ and its adjoints, this question could be phrased: Can the $A_n$'s determine a maximal directed set of $A$'s proper sub-vN-algebras, "modulo finite sets"?

[I ask this question because, as a student in general topology, I've been looking in vain for something analogous in other spaces (measure spaces, Hilbert spaces, etc.). Loosely speaking, I've found you can always diagonalize out some elements of your $A_n$'s to make a new subspace $B$ that violates (appropriate analogs of) both (1) and (2) above, for all $n$ and $F$. I believe this procedure works with abelian vN algebras too. But I'm informed that not all vN algebras might be vulnerable to it, because their "weaker" topologies might make any diagonalized subalgebra have a "big enough" closure to satisfy (2) for some $n$ and $F$. Sounds plausible, but having skimmed through Kadison & Ringrose's text, it seems like it'd be hard work to make this precise, so ... is anyone aware of relevant results, positive or negative? Or even hints or hunches? I would be so, so, grateful!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't expect a straightforward answer to your question.

Suppose that $A$ is finitely generated, i.e. $A=F_0''$ for some finite $F_0$. Then, for any sequence $\{A_n\}$, for any $B\subseteq A$, for any $n$, you can take $F=F_0$ and then $B\subseteq A=F_0''=(A_n\cup F_0)''$.

The problem is that it is not known if every von Neumann algebra is finitely generated; it is known that all but type II$_1$ direct summands are singly generated. A counterexample to your question would provide an example of a von Neumann algebra $A$ that is not finitely generated; no such is example is known to this day.

Comment: On the contrary, you have given a very straightforward answer -- I asked if any sequence of vN algebras can meet that requirement, and you pointed out that indeed some can. (The question of which vN algebras *fail* to have such subalgebra sequences seems harder, as you say.)

Comment: I hadn't known, from my readings in Kadison/Ringrose and elsewhere, that most vN algebras are finitely generated. This surprises me, probably because I hadn't appreciated how much richer the "generating operations" (addition, composition, perhaps involution?) are in this context, compared to those I'd been looking at (usually just intersection, union, complementation). Thanks again -- this is extremely helpful! -- I will ponder and see if I can re-pose the question with a weaker form of "generation" than the double-commutant, so that it's perhaps more interesting.

Comment: Good point: if the vN algebra has no II$_1$ summand, then it is singly generated. I don't think this is mentioned at all in KR. The results that show that all other types of separable (I forgot to include this, of course finitely generated implies separable) vN algebras are singly generated are from the late 60s and 70s. What is really rich is not that much the $*$-algebra operations (which they are to a certain extent) but the weak operator topology; for instance, consider this result that appears as an exercise in KR: every positive contraction in $B(H)$ is a wot limit of projections.